# PHP: Generating PDF by fetching data from database

Tags: php, mysql, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

I Have just started to learn PHP. As a task,

I submitted a form which sent the values to the MySQL database, Now, I want to fetch these values from the database and display it in a letterhead format and then have to output that letterhead as a PDF file.

Please suggest me a way to do that from the basic level, I tried to follow 1-2 questions here but couldnt get any results. I need a step-by-step procedure...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your work can't be done by us. so please search and research again. PHP itself provides a good way to generate pdf. If you don't like it you can go for a library such as fpdf. 
You should google it first. try some code. Then you will get most errors. If you can't find a solution for that errors. You can post a question seeking help. We can help you.

Here is the link for [Php pdf documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdf.examples-basic.php)
Here is the link for [fpdf php library website](http://www.fpdf.org/)